# Encontrar las diferencias entre arrays de tipo indice => array en PHP

Tags: php, array

Necesito encontrar las diferencias entre dos arrays con la siguiente estructura:

```
array([0] => array([ciudad] => "Londres" [pais] => "Inglaterra") [1] => array([ciudad] => "París" [pais] => "Francia")... [n] => array([ciudad] => "Roma" [pais] => "Italia"))
```

Al intentar aplicar array_diff obtengo un array vacío a pesar de que hay pares (ciudad, país) en el primer array que no se encuentran en el segundo; creo que el problema es que la función no es capaz de entrar en los arrays internos y los ve todos iguales.

Estoy probando a hacer una comparación más elaborada a través de un if dentro de un bucle for pero tampoco está dando buenos resultados:

```
$localizaciones_distintas = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($localizaciones_bd); $i++) 
{ 
    if ($localizaciones[$i] != $localizaciones_bd[$i]) array_push($localizaciones_distintas, $localizaciones[$i]);
}
```

¿Se os ocurre cómo solventarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado una solución:

```
$localizaciones_distintas = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($localizaciones); $i++) 
{
    if (!in_array($localizaciones[$i], $localizaciones_bd)) array_push($localizaciones_distintas, $localizaciones[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la funcion array_diff_key

```
array_diff_key($array1, $array2);
```

Referencia:
[array_diff_key](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff-key.php)

Comment: Byro, no elimines y publiques otra respuesta, si tienes mas info que añadir; basta con que le das editar a tu respuesta y puedes modificar todo el contenido

Comment: No me dejaba la app, salia retry cada ves que intente editarla =(